# Get the Network Interface Name in C#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, pcap, winpcap

I'm writing a program which uses the wPCAP library. I managed to get out the list of interface names:

> \Device\NPF_{A9734063-CA83-4D91-A35B-CC727749256A
>   ...

Now my question is: how do I know which interface this is? I'm attempting to get the IP of the interface with that name.

I tried the `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` function, but in those classes I could only find the "readable" name, and not the \Device... name.

Thank you!

Yvan

Edit: I need to get the IP address of the device with the name "\Device\NPF_...". How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution to circumvent the problem: I just listen on each interface :-S.
That does accomplish also a desireable result (namely the logging of each visited web page).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that it's more a device problem than a network problem see :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DeviceStatus.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: But, how do I get the IP address of such a device with only the Device ID?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216 if you use the device ID you should be able to get everything you need

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I did something similar.  Look up the following and I am sure you will find what you are looking for:

IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();

Comment: Yeah, I know. I have the IP. But how do I convert the adapter class to a \Device\... id? That's the method I'm looking for...

Comment: Ah ok, you could try the managementobjectsearcher: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx